# How do I retrieve a child Class for Java reflection?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, reflection, parent

So, this is going to sound like an odd question, but **I need to know how to get the `Class` object of a child `Object` in an inheritance situation for Java reflection**.

The situation is this: I'm writing CraftBukkit plugins, Java plugins that work with CraftBukkit, a server-side-only plugin A.P.I. for Minecraft. At the moment, I'm making a plugin that is supposed to be like a "parent" to all of the other plugins I'm writing. It contains large amounts of extra useful Objects and utilities.

One class in the plugin is an Object class called `myPlugin` that I want all the main classes of all the other plugins to `extend`. (I know Object names shouldn't start with a lowercase letter, but the lowercase "my" is a trademark with my CraftBukkit plugins.)

One of the things that I want this `myPlugin` class to do is be able to handle commands to load plugins' data. Therefore, when the command is called, **I want the plugin to basically call all of the methods in the plugin's main class that start with "load"**.

I know how to search through all the Methods in the `Class` for ones starting with "load" if I can just retrieve the `Class`, but **if I try to call `getClass()` in the `myPlugin` class, I believe it's just going to return the `myPlugin` `Class` instead of the `Class` that extends `myPlugin`**.

So, **how can I retrieve the `Class` that extends `myPlugin` instead of the `myPlugin` class itself?**

EDIT:
I feel that I should mention that I've considered creating an `abstract` method called `mainClass()` that will return the Class and making each plugin add this method and return their main class, but this is an ugly fix that I would prefer to avoid.

Comment: `getClass()` returns the `Class` object for the instance it is called on, regardless of where the invocation occurs.

Comment: *"I believe it's just going to return the myPlugin Class instead of the Class that extends myPlugin"* You believe wrong. It will return **that** class class, not the parent one, not anything else.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis @m0skit0 If that's the case, then how would you ever be able to retrieve the `myPlugin` `Class` object if that were needed for some other reason?

Comment: There are different ways. `myPlugin.class` is one. `Class.forName("some.qualified.name.myPlugin")` is another.

Comment: Also, if you have a `myPlugin` instance, then `getClass()` on that instance will also return the `Class` object for `myPlugin`.

Comment: All right then. Thanks for your help. I guess I just misunderstood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's the subclass name that is returned, consider:

```
public class ClassOne {

}

public class ClassTwo extends ClassOne {

}

public class Test {

    public void someMethod(ClassOne one) {

        System.out.println(one.getClass().getName());
    }

}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ClassTwo t = new ClassTwo();
        Test tst = new Test();
        tst.someMethod(t);
    }

}
```

The output is: ClassTwo